# Boto: how to keep EMR job flow running after completion/failure?

Tags: python, boto, amazon-emr

How can I add steps to a waiting Amazon EMR job flow using boto without the job flow terminating once complete?

I've created an interactive job flow on Amazon's Elastic Map Reduce and loaded some tables. When I pass in new steps to the job flow using Boto's `emr_conn.add_jobflow_steps(...)`, the job flow terminates after it finishes or fails.

I know I can start a job flow with boto using `run_jobflow` with the `keep_alive` parameter -- but I'd like to work with flows that are already running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it finishes correctly, it should not terminate with `keep_alive=True`.  That said, it would normally exit on failure, so you want to add `terminate_on_failure="CONTINUE"` to your `add_job_steps` arguments.

Answer (score 2):

I use something like this

create with

```
import boto.emr

conn = boto.emr.connect_to_region('us-west-2')
jobid = conn.run_jobflow(name='cluster-name',
                     ec2_keyname="yourkeyhere",
                     num_instances=3,
                     master_instance_type='m1.medium',
                     slave_instance_type='m1.medium',
                     keep_alive=True,
)
```

add a job to an existing cluster with (wait a little for cluster to be in waiting state)

```
import boto.emr

conn = boto.emr.connect_to_region('us-west-2')
# get the list of waiting cluster and take the first one
jobid =  conn.describe_jobflows(states=["WAITING"])[0].jobflowid
print jobid
flow_steps = list()
runThing = boto.emr.step.ScriptRunnerStep(
                        name="job step name",
                        step_args = ["s3://yours3bucket/dosmthg.sh"])
flow_steps.append(runThing)
conn.add_jobflow_steps(jobid, flow_steps)
```

notes

- you need to have ~/.aws/credentials filled up (aws configure)
- amazon region us-west-2 currently has the more recent ami version
- you can may have to add bootstrap_actions= if you need hive, pig or custom installation steps

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with the 'KeepJobFlowAliveWhenNoSteps' flag.

```
response = emr.run_job_flow(
        Name="start-my-cluster",
        ReleaseLabel="emr-5.3.1",
        LogUri='s3://logs',
        Instances={
            'InstanceGroups': [
                {'Name': 'EmrMaster',
                 'InstanceRole': 'MASTER',
                 'InstanceType': 'm3.xlarge',
                 'InstanceCount': 1},
                {'Name': 'EmrCore',
                 'InstanceRole': 'CORE',
                 'InstanceType': 'm3.xlarge',
                 'InstanceCount': 2}
            ],
            'Ec2KeyName': 'my-key-name',
            'KeepJobFlowAliveWhenNoSteps' : True,
        },
        Applications=[{'Name': 'Hadoop'}, {'Name': 'Spark'}, {'Name': 'Hive'}],
        JobFlowRole='EMR_EC2_DefaultRole',
        ServiceRole='EMR_DefaultRole',
        VisibleToAllUsers=True,
        Steps=[
            # steps go here...
        ]
        )
```

Comment: How can you terminate the cluster when you're done with it though? Because if you set that flag it's never going to terminate.

Comment: You call `emr.terminate_job_flows(JobFlowIds=[cluster_id])` to terminate a running cluster. I've added a complete example that shows how to create a long-lived cluster, add steps, and manually terminate it on [GitHub](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/904ccdab93220d59eb45bdc9c299288036406e5d/python/example_code/emr/emr_usage_demo.py#L433).